# How can I change "unlocked" default text showing in react swipe button

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am working on react swipe button. By default it shows "unlocked" on button. I am using [react swipe button yarn package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/react-swipe-button) . How can I change the text "unlocked" to "Completed"?

[image: Need to change the text "unlocked" to"completed"]

Comment: Hi, try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and what it's doing and how you are trying to modify the button text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Next time I will take care of all points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rinasm/react-swipe-button/blob/master/src/index.js#L81), and it seems like there's a `text_unlocked` prop you can pass to the component.

```
<ReactSwipeButton
   ... 
   text_unlocked='Completed'
/>
```

Note that it doesn't seem to be listed as part of the [official documentation](https://github.com/rinasm/react-swipe-button#props), so you may run into problems if the developer did not intend to expose this property.